# How can I kill a ruby thread after a certain amount of time?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I want a thread that I create to die if it doesn't finish after a certain amount of time. Is there any elegant and/or idiomatic way to do this? Right now I am thinking to make a watcher thread:

```
def myfunc
  t = Thread.new{
    #do stuff
  }

  # watcher thread
  Thread.new{
    result = t.join(20) # join returns nil if it timed out
    t.kill if result.nil?
  }

  # continue on asynchronously from both threads
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe the [Timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) class is what you need.

```
def myfunc
  Thread.new{
    Timeout::timeout(20) {
      #do stuff
    }
  }

  # continue on asynchronously
end
```

Comment: ah ha, great! i editing your answer to include an example of how to use it to solve the problem...

Comment: I think you don't need to wrap the Timeout object inside a Thread. The Timeout makes a thread for the code block, so you don't have to, unless you want the whole thing to be asynchronous.

Comment: Yep, I want it to be asynchronous -- that's sort of the point, I want the thread to clean itself up if it gets stuck.

Answer (score 4):

I believe in most situation, you should control the "life" of thread by the program logic in the thread.

Assume the thread is actually a infinite loop, instead of having a plain while(true), you may have an instance variable (e.g. is_running) and make the loop being something like while(is_running).  If other thread wanna stop this thread, they can simply (directly or indirectly) make is_running false.  The working thread then can finish off the last piece of work on hand and finish the loop.

Comment: True. However in this case I want to absolutely kill it if it takes too long.